# Textbook Recommendation: Statistics

Tags: statistics, reference-request

I am still a freshmen taking statistics and am disappointed with a second semester statistical theory course which just raves on from typical distributions to bi-variate random variables to random variable functions and Order Statistics.

I am mad with my teacher who pretty much expects the class to "remember" he theories and fails to explain their origin or source.

Although I am yet to learn Analysis or collegiate integral calculus for that matter I found this book "An Outline of Statistical Theory - Goon, Gupta, Dasgupta" which teaches probability from a measure theoretic perspective and am enjoying it. Although I don't get concepts like the Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral, I am however enjoying the rigor and the grassroot teaching of the book.

Looking for books on measure theory/ Probability that might further help me understand statistics properly instead of superficially. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recommend a statistics fundamentals book](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6254/recommend-a-statistics-fundamentals-book)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/315075/321264

Answer (score 2):

To understand statistics from the very grassroots, I think the book [Statistics, 4th edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0393929728) by Freedman, Purves, Pisani will be very appropriate. The most basic book on Probability is [An Introduction to Probability Theory and Its Applications, Vol. 1, 3rd Edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471257087) by Feller. And you are telling me that you are not also sure about Lebesgue-Stieltjes Integral. You have to strengthen your Real Analysis skills very much before you should start Measure theory. A very good book on Real Analysis is [Real Mathematical Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387952977) by Charles C. Pugh. This book also includes basic Measure thoery.