# Equivalent to Tao's Analysis 1 Book for Statistics

Tags: statistics, reference-request, book-recommendation

I am looking a book recommendation that is equivalent to Tao's Analysis I for Statistics. Would you share your recommendations?

In particular, it would be ideal to find a book that starts with a measure-theoretic probability set-up and takes off from there, published primarily aiming for advanced undergrad or first-year Ph.D. student readers.

Note I am not looking for a probability book, but a statistics book.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Bickel and Doksum ?

Comment: Any suggestions? Anyone?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/51785/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/315075/book-on-measure-theoretic-statistics?noredirect=1&lq=1