# Statistics - Book Recommendation

Tags: statistics, book-recommendation

I am taking a course in statistics. It covers:

Parameter estimations: point and interval estimations, etc.

Hypothesis testing: comparison of means, comparison of probabilities, Chi square tests, etc.

Analysis of variance..

And the like.

What are some books that you would recommend for such a course?

Thanks.

Comment: I think Larson Intro to Probability and Statistics is really good.  It's out of print but you can find a used copy for like $5 on amazon: http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Probability-Theory-Statistical-Inference/dp/0471059099/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1430855758&sr=8-1&keywords=larson+probability

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recommend a statistics fundamentals book](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6254/recommend-a-statistics-fundamentals-book)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/51785/321264

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There aren't anywhere nearly as many good mathematical introductions on statistics as there are on it's parent subject probability. It's a hard subject to clearly write about because there's no generally accepted manner of approaching the subject. About all the experts agree on about it is that it involves using probability distribution functions to test hypotheses.

Trust me-my teacher,Stefan Ralescu,**is** an expert.

My favorite book on statistics is George Casella and Robert Berger's *Statistical Inference*. Not only is it wonderfully clear and rigorous, requiring only a good understanding of one and several variable calculus, it covers an *enormous* number of examples. Sadly,most books don't do this and it's really important with a subject this unusual. It's a bit pricey, but well worth the cost.