# Can any one recommend a statistics book?

Tags: probability, statistics, reference-request, statistical-inference, book-recommendation

I am currently a second-year graduate student in statistics. I have taken the course with the textbook Statistical inference by George Casella and Roger L. Berger.

I have learned some basic concepts such as sufficient statistics,  complete sufficient statistics,  UMVUE and etc. Though I found all these concepts are in one-dimensional case in this book.  Can anyone recommend a book that covers these concepts in a multivariate or high dimensional case?  Especially, a textbook with practice questions and a solution manual is preferred.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what exactly you mean by 'one-dimensional case' regarding the topics you mentioned? I guess multivariate extensions of these topics are often immediate, so they are not specifically discussed.

Comment: It is not multivariate problems.  For example, the majority of the problems do not use matrix  and vectors.

Comment: You can check out *Theory of Point Estimation* by E.L. Lehmann (there are two other books by the same author on hypothesis testing and asymptotic theory) and *Mathematical Statistics* by Shao. Both of these are advanced texts on [inference](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/51785/321264).