# Reference for statistical inference concerning these topics

Tags: reference-request, statistical-inference, book-recommendation, lecture-notes

I am looking for book recommendations /lecture notes for self studying Inference. Following are the main topics of concern:

> Parametric models, parameters, random sample and its likelihood,
> statistic and its sampling distributions, problems of inference.
> Examples from standard discrete and continuous models such as
> Bernoulli, Binomial, Poisson, Negative Binomial, Normal, Exponential,
> Gamma, Weibull, Pareto etc. Concept of sufficiency, minimal
> sufficiency, Neyman factorization criterion, Fisher information,
> exponential families. Maximum likelihood estimators, method of moment
> estimators, percentile estimators, least squares estimators, minimum
> mean squares estimators, uniformly minimum variance unbiased
> estimators, Rao Blackwell theorem, Cramer Rao lower bond, different
> examples. Statistical Hypotheses simple and composite, statistical
> tests, critical regions, Type I and Type II errors, size and power of
> a test, Neyman Pearson lemma and its different applications. Most
> powerful test, uniformly most powerful test, unbiased test and
> uniformly most unbiased test. Likelihood ratio test. Interval
> estimation, confidence intervals, construction of confidence
> intervals, shortest expected length confidence interval, most accurate
> one sided confidence interval and its relation to UMP test.

Kindly suggest some good texts or lecture notes to help me break ice into this topic.

Comment: "Statistical Inference" by Casella and Berger is a standard reference and a good book.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/51785/321264

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend Probability and Statistical Inference by Hogg, Tenis, and Zimmerman (10th edition specifically!!).
I am not sponsored, but this book helped me a lot when I was trying to self study. Steps were easy to follow.

Chapter 1 introduces the the properties of the probability, counting rues, independent/dependent/mutually exclusive events, Bayes etc.

Then the Chapter 2 introduces all the Discrete distributions and the properties of them like you mentioned - Bernoulli, Binomial, Hypergeometric, Negative Binomial, and Poison distributions.

Chapter 3 introduces all the continuous distributions like Beta, Gamma, Exponential, Chi-square, Normal and Uniform distributions.

Chapter 5 introduces transformations and functions of random variables, moment generating function, central limit theorem, sampling distribution, Normal distribution, Z-distribution, and derivation of student t-distribution chebyshe's inequality, and more.

Chapter 6 introduces descriptive statistics(sample mean, sample variance, relative frequency, empirical rules, etc), sample percentile, quartiles, five-number summaries, Min, Max, Range, IQR, Box plot, order statistics, Maximum likelihood and estimators, method of moments estimation, biased/unbiased estimators,assymptotic distributions of maximum likelihood estimators, sufficient statistics, simple regression, and Bayesian estimation and more.

Chapter 7 basically talks about confidence interval for various distributions that we talked about chapter 2&3, sample size, and resampling methods.

Chapter 8 introduces definition of hypothesis and different types of statistical tests - test of equality of two means, test of equal variance, test of equal proportions and many more. Also talks about distribution-free hypothesis tests(nonparametric methods) - Wilcoxon's signed rank test and Wilcoxon's rank sum test.It also talks about critical region, type 1 error, type 2 error, significance level, p-value, power of a statistical test. When and how to reject the null hypothesis.

I haven yet studied chapter 9, but I hope you may find this book covers some of keywords that you mentions above and more.

Thank.